# value gets updated on all instances of field

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the below code which is meant to calculate two fields from each instance (row) of an insert.

currently it populates all the 'total' fields rather than just the one for the corresponding row.

also inserts 'NaN' into all the total fields.

```
var LabourItems = {
   rate: null,
   hours: null,
   total: null,
   init: function(object) {
      var rate = $(object).children('.rate').first();
      var hours =$(object).children('.hours').first();
      this.total = Number(rate) * Number(hours);
      this.updateTotal(object);
   },
   updateTotal: function(object) {
      $(object).children('.total').first().attr('value', this.total)
   }
}

//reactTochange for those inputs that you want to observe
$('.hours').live("click", function() {
   jQuery.each($('.labouritems'), function(key,value){
      LabourItems.init(value);
   });
});
```

Comment: What else than `NaN` do you expect when passing jQuery instances into `Number()`?

Comment: meaning `this.total = Number(rate.val()) * Number(hours.val());` should work better. Also use .on instead of .live which is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You haven't taken the *value* of the fields:

```
var rate = parseInt($(object).children('.rate').val(), 10);
```

[ No need for `.first()` as that's implicit when using `.val()` to read]

Also, you should use `.val()` to *set* the total value too, not `.attr('value', ...)`.

Comment: hiya, The NaN has stopped but not getting the Total to populate into the field